# MarkLogic: Converting an XML document into an XML string using XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

I am using something like

```
let $x := 
 "<root>
 <parent1>value1</parent1>
 <parent2>value2</parent2>
 </root>"
...
```

and converting the XML document to string. I wanted to pass an xml output from a function to another function as a string and not by hard coding it as I'm doing it right now.

I tried using `fn:string`, but that doesn't pick up the xml tags as string.

Comment: You might want to think a little about why you are doing this. Normally you work with XML nodes as nodes, not strings. There are exceptions, but they aren't common.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you simply want the opposite of [xdmp:unquote](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:unquote) - which is called [xdmp:quote](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:quote)

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";    
let $x := xdmp:quote(<root>
         <parent1>value1</parent1>
         <parent2>value2</parent2>
         </root>)

return $x
```